# Matching color of a cell with another cell using VBA

Tags: excel, cell, vba

I am required to write some VBA code so that, if I assign it to a command button, by clicking it I should be able to match the color of cells C11 and cell C4.

Suppose I change the color of C11 to red, the color of C4 should change to red by click of a command button or automatically.

Can some one help me with this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the macro recorder then setting the colour - that would give you some code to work with, then you need to look at event-handlers and conditional statements in the VBA documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code copies the color value from cell "C11" to cell "C4":

```
Range("C4").Interior.Color = Range("C11").Interior.Color
```

As long as you work with valid Range-Objects, you can use different types to address the cells as fits your needs. For example the active selection (at least one cell or more):

```
Selection.Interior.Color = Range("C11").Interior.Color
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Verzweifler...it helped